# Implement stateless authentication with HTML5 audio / video (and plain images), is it possible?

Tags: rest, authentication, html5-video, state, html5-audio

We have a REST style API and try to follow the REST principles as close as possible, so of course that includes statelessness as well.

While the most part of our backend is indeed stateless, there is one thing that seems impossible to achieve, and that is dealing with authentication of non API related static resources.  I understand that there are means to achieve stateless auth using some token based approaches (e.g. JWT). But that requires setting some headers or transferring credential information in the requests' message body.

This would be no problem when only API requests have to be secured, as we easily can modify XHR or fetch requests accordingly.

But the problem is that we also need to secure static resources like images and audio/video files. For images I *could* load them via XHR/fetch, though this is already quite cumbersome compared to using a plain image tag.

But as soon as it comes to html5 video/audio, I haven't found a way to achieve this, is it possible at all?

Currently we just use a secured httpOnly cookie, so in that case it is no problem with either images or audio. May using a cookie (having a JWT like payload) generated by the client could be a solution? Of course this would open another potential security issue since now - in case of a XSS breach - the cookie and its information could be stolen which is impossible with a httponly cookie.

Any ideas to achieve a pure stateless authentication that also works for images and html5 audio or video (and that is not less secure as well)?

PS: HTTP Basic Auth is **not** an option for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No ideas? Hmmm. OK so *maybe* I can answer my own question ...

A potential solution would be to use something like a JWT, but still use a
 cookie as the transport mechanism. So the token is generated on the
 server, and set via cookie, just like it has been before with the traditional session cookie. Seems like I could have the "best of both
 worlds" with this approach:

- The client still has no means to access the contents of the cookie,
  and therefore does not need to know anything about authorisation. The only thing the client has
  to know is the concept of authentication, i.e. asking the user for the
  credentials and sending them to the server as soon as a 401 is
  returned.
- The server is now freed of doing any session management, all it has to do
  is validating the token.
- And, most importantly: this will work not only for requests where I can manipulate the header and/or message body (like with XHR/fetch) but for any type of static resource as well, including images and html5 audio & video

Does this sound like a good solution? Vote up this answer if you think it is! Thank you.